# How do I break out of a play framework template loop?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Given a loop in template like this:

```
@for(item <- items) {   
    @if(item.id == 42) {    
        BREAK
    }
}
```

How can I make it break? Is break/continue construct available to use in play framework template?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `items` is a Scala collection, the idiomatic approach is not to break, but to filter out the elements you don't want to process before you start iterating.

I'm guessing that your collection is ordered by ID, and your intention is to stop once you get to item 42. If this indeed is the case, I'd go for this:

```
@for(item <- items.filter(_.id < 42)) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: If it is not ordered and the plan is to stop at first 42 (excluded) then that would be `item <- items.takeWhile(_.id != 42)`

Comment: Actually, that's not exactly the problem. I've simplified the loop so it would be clear what language construct I'd like to use. In most template languages I've encountered break/continue idiom was available. I am curious if such construction can be used in play framework template.

Comment: @szymond This is not specific to play templates at all, but instead the scala language. Didier's comment will do exactly what you're asking in place of `break`.